# igraph --- find shortest path including weight at turns

Tags: r, algorithm, igraph

The following example gives shortest path 1-2-6-7-3-4, where only the weight of edges is considered; and the weight of turn at vertices is not counted for. Can someone suggest a procedure to include the weight at each vertex that is no-turn, right-turn, or left-turn?  We can assume the weight for (NT, RT, LT)=(0,0.5,1). When edge weight is combined with turn effect, the shortest path would become 1-2-3-4. Below is the example in question.  Thank you.

#

```
library(igraph)
n <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x <- c(1,4,7,10,1,4,7,10)
y <- c(1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4)
node <- data.frame(n,x,y)
fm <- c(1,2,3,5,6,7,1,2,3,4)
to<-c(2,3,4,6,7,8,5,6,7,8)
weight<- c(1,4,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1)
link <- data.frame(fm,to,weight)
g <- graph.data.frame(link,directed=FALSE,vertices=node)
sv <- get.shortest.paths(g,1,4,weights=NULL,output="vpath")
sv
E(g)$color <- "pink"
E(g, path=sv[[1]])$width <- 8
plot(g,edge.color="red") 
plot(g,edge.label=weight,edge.label.color="blue",edge.label.cex=2)
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to combine the vertex and edge weights into the edge weights? You can make the graph directed, and then have different weights when going opposite directions.

Comment: @GaborCsardi: the vertex weights aren't fixed, since they depend on the direction that you approach that vertex from. This is probably going to require hand-coding a shortest path algorithm like Dijkstra's, with a bit of extra code to add the cost of the turns.

Comment: What I mean is to add the weight of the vertex to the weight of the _outgoing_ edge. You need to make the graph directed, and then add the weight of A to the weight of A->B and the weight of B to the weight of B->A. I can't see why this would not work. Isn't it the same solution @jeffrey is suggesting?

Comment: @Gabor Csardi, I have been trying to program according to comment by Jeffrey. Now I understand that each N-leg vertex in my network needs be replaced with a mini-graph of 2*N vertices and N(N-1) one-way edges. My Los Angeles network now has 385,000 vertices and 493,000 edges. Applying his method, the final expanded network will become a graph with 1.6 million vertices and 2.6 million edges. Is there any limit for the size of graph that igraph or get.shortest.paths can handle? Thank you for your advice. –

Comment: @user2989958: there is no limit, but if you want to calculate all shortest paths, I don't think you have enough memory in your computer for that.

Answer (score 0):

As a preprocessing step: for each vertex `v` with `a` incoming edges and `b` outgoing edges, split it into `a` vertexes connected to those incoming edges and `b` vertexes connected to those outgoing edges. Then create edges representing turning costs in between.

Comment: Dear Jeffrey, Thank you for your suggestion. If I understand correctly, to implement your answer, each N-leg vertex in the network will be replaced with N vertices and N(N-1)/2 edges. Your solution should work for small test network, but I don't know how our real network for Los Angeles will become after this conversion. Is there a less demanding approach?

Comment: Jeffrey, I have been trying to program according to your suggestion. Now I understand that each N-leg vertex in my network needs be replaced with a mini-graph of 2*N vertices and N(N-1) one-way edges. My Los Angeles network now has 385,000 vertices and 493,000 edges. Applying your method, the final expanded network will become a graph with 1.6 million vertices and 2.6 million edges. Is there any limit for the size of graph that igraph or get.shortest.paths can handle? Thank you for your advice.

Comment: @user2989958: I see your point. If your graph is dense (each node has a lot of edges), the size of the new graph generated by my algorithm can be large. However, I cannot come up with a better solution, and I am not sure whether others can.

Answer (score 0):

In principal, Jeffery is describing what we want, but the problem size is such that we need a programmatic solution.  Maybe 200,000 vertices with 3 to 6 edges.  If there is a way to explode, for instance, the standard intersection of 4 edges in and 4 edges out to the 16 right through left movements and automatically assigning left through and right penalties.

most important is the ability to have lesser penalties for turning at T intersections (ease of wayfinding) than turning at traditional intersections/vertices

Is this  tractable for a huge network?